# Why is Google Analytics not tracking any events?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've implemented pretty much the standard examples:

```
        <script>

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-mycode']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

        </script>

        <script>

            function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
                try {
                    var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
                    _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category ,  action ]);
                    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
                }catch(err){}
            }

        </script>
```

and the links have this onclick event:

```
<a id="latestDownload" href="https://example.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'newDownloads', 'latest');return false;">Download latest version</a>
```

No events have been tracked for the past 3 days, which just sound wrong to me. I've tested the page with the GA debug plugin for chrome, which shows events are send.

Have I made some mistake here?

The Google GA debug addon shows (literally, not obfuscated):

```
Account ID : UA-XXXXX-X

&utmac=UA-XXXXX-X
```

Do I need to push the '_setAccount' again?

Comment: could you give us a link to your site - this problem is really hard to debug only looking at your code. implementation seems correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr... leave out the `_getTrackerByName()` call, just use

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category ,  action ]);
```

Longer explanation: Async tracking allows pushing commands to multiple trackers (see [Tracking Basics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands)) using a syntax like

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2']);
_gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
```

The `_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category ,  action ]);` code assumes you've already initialized `myTracker` like the `b` tracker above.

Since `myTracker` has never had an accountId set, it shows the `UA-XXXXX-X` accountId while debugging.

The analytics code on [Specialized Tracking/Outbound Links](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920) is wrong, or would only work if the setup code named `myTracker`.

Comment: Makes sense. Do i even need the 'myTracker' reference? Seeing how '_trackPageview' does without?

Comment: Correct, no need for the myTracker reference or the _getTrackerByName call

Comment: Ok! I've updated my pages. @dragon's answer is also correct, but this has more explaination.

Answer (score 2):

`myTracker` is a variable, so you cannot really refer to it inside a string. Following should work:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category ,  action ]);
```

Comment: cant you concatenate it then? _gaq.push([myTracker+'._trackEvent', category ,  action ]);

Comment: It is, however, the exact example Google provides: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920

Comment: @ŁukaszRysiak `myTracker` is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout thing seems a bit risky to me - it assumes that the Google Analytics call has been made within 100 ms.

I prefer this:

```
function trackOutboundLink(url) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound', 'click']);

    _gaq.push(function() {
        window.location = url;
    });
}
```

This queues up the redirect until after the Google Analytics async call has completed.

To hook up:

```
<a href="#" onclick="trackOutboundLink('your-url');return false;">Link</a>
```